# Efficiently generate clamped arrays from non-clamped array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a bit of code that compares two images.  To get the canvas data of an image, I use this:

```
 const canvasOneImageData = canvasOneContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvasOne.width, canvasOne.height);
```

My goal is to construct a series of `rgba` `Uint8ClampedArrays` to represent each of the pixels from this buffer.  I currently use the following:

```
const canvasOneBuffer = new Uint8Array(canvasOneImageData.data.buffer);
// within an x/y loop:
const newPixel1Data0 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 0]; // r
const newPixel1Data1 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 1]; // g
const newPixel1Data2 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 2]; // b
const newPixel1Data3 = canvasOneBuffer[4 * (x + y * canvasOne.width) + 3]; // a
const pixel1Data = new Uint8ClampedArray(4);
pixel1Data[0] = newPixel1Data0;
pixel1Data[1] = newPixel1Data1;
pixel1Data[2] = newPixel1Data2;
pixel1Data[3] = newPixel1Data3;
```

This seems a bit obtuse though.  Is there any way I can go about creating the new `Uint8ClampedArray(4);` with a single read from the buffer array and a single write to the new array?

I know I can use `canvasOneBuffer.slice(0, 4)` - but this still requires a piecemeal clamped array composition.  Performance is the biggest priority here as this will be done hundreds of times per second.

Comment: What do you mean by "piecemeal clamped array composition"? Also, can you explain what you're trying to do with this code?

Comment: pixel1Data=canvasOneBuffer; im not shure if it is really necessary to *clamp* it...

Comment: @4castle - added some context, though I don't think it will help much.  I mean I still have to push the pixel data individually into the clamped array (I think anyways).

Comment: @Jonasw I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but I do indeed need clamped arrays here.

Comment: canvasOneImageData.data already contains a clamped array. So couldnt you just change your algorithm to just check specific parts if this e.g. 0-4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pixelData=canvasOneImageData.data;
```

Image data is already a clamped array in js. I think it would be best to iterate over it in a four bytes eachway:

```
for(var i=0;i<pixelData.length-3;i+=4){
  var pixel1=pixelData[i];
  var pixel2=pixelData[i+1];
  var pixel3=pixelData[i+2];
  var pixel4=pixelData[i+3];
  //...
}
```

If you really want subarrays, you could use *TypedArray.prototype.subarray* :

```
var pixel1Data=canvasOneImageData.data.subarray(0,4);
```

Note that this refernces to the same buffer. So the performance is really high, but its not a copy, so modifying modifies the image too. If you dont want this, may use *.slice*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray

Comment: I'm a little confused - given 64 pixels, `canvasOneImageData.data` has 256 entries.  I'm trying to create 64 clamped subarrays out of this the fastest way possible.  Are you saying to just do `0,4`, `5,8` etc using `subarray`?  I just need reading; I won't be modifying the pixel data.

Comment: @SB2055 simply for loop over the big clamped array?

Comment: The idea is that I have two images and I'm comparing pixels on each.  The comparison function - `pixelsAreDifferent(p1, p2)` - requires two Uint8CLampedArray(4) to represent pixels (rgba).  So I need to read through the buffer and generate these sub-arrays to pass in - one sub-array at a time.

Comment: @SB2055 what should pixelsAreDifferent do, and what should the whole code do? i think that can be optimized. Creating subarrays is quite fast if the buffer stays the same, however, im not shure if this is really necessary in this case. cant you just do pixelsAreDifferent(Apixel1,Apixel2,Apixel3,Apixel4,Bpixel1...) or inline the function?